# WebSQL recursive loop after db.transaction is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am trying to loop through a set of results returned from a `db.transaction`. In this loop I am appending html content to a JavaScript variable, which, once the loop is completed is added to the DOM using jQuery's `html()` function. This works as expected.

The problem is that during the loop, I am making another `db.transaction` query. The problem I am having is the second query (within the loop) is not completing before moving to the next iteration of the loop.

I originally used a `for()` loop, but figured that this is what was causing the issue, since the for loop had no way to know whether the `db.transaction` within the loop was completed yet.

So I decided to go with a recursive loop, which looks like:

```
var html_content = '<table class="booking-table"><tbody>';
var i = 0;

function getPhotoCountForSyncItemSuccessRecursive(i){
    html_content += "More HTML content, not relevant"
    localStorage.setItem("current_row_booking_id", results.rows.item(i).id);
    i++;
    db.transaction(getPhotoCountForSyncItem, getPhotoCountForSyncItemFailRecursive,                 getPhotoCountForSyncItemSuccessRecursive(i));

    if (i == results.rows.length){
        html_content += '</tbody></table>';
        $('.booking-items-wrapper').html(html_content);
    }
}

getPhotoCountForSyncItemSuccessRecursive(i);
```

So, first off I am setting 2 variables, one to hold the html content (**html_content**), and another to hold the count for the current result (**i**)

Next is the function declaration `getPhotoCountForSyncItemSuccessRecursive()` which accepts one argument, the current count (**i**). After this function, I am calling the function to start the recursive loop.

Within the function, I am doing a large amount of appending (not shown here as it is irrelevant) to the html_content variable. I am then setting a `localStorage` value called `current_row_booking_id` which has a value of the current results id (and is used in the second query shortly).

I then increment the count, and call the recursive part of the function:

```
db.transaction(getPhotoCountForSyncItem, getPhotoCountForSyncItemFailRecursive, getPhotoCountForSyncItemSuccessRecursive(i));
```

As you can see, I call a function `getPhotoCountForSyncItem`, and on success, call the recursive function `getPhotoCountForSyncItemSuccessRecursive(i)` (creating my loop)

My `getPhotoCountForSyncItem` (and its success and fail callbacks) look like:

```
function getPhotoCountForSyncItem(tx){
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM booking_photo WHERE booking_id = '" + localStorage.getItem("current_row_booking_id") + "'", [], getPhotoCountForSyncItemSuccess, getPhotoCountForSyncItemFail);
}

function getPhotoCountForSyncItemFail(tx, results){
  console.log("getPhotoCountForSyncItemFail");
  localStorage.removeItem("current_row_booking_id");
}

function getPhotoCountForSyncItemSuccess(tx, results){
    if (results.rows.length == 0){
        console.log('no photos');
        localStorage.removeItem("current_row_booking_id");
    } else {
        console.log('got photos ' + results.rows.length);
        localStorage.removeItem("current_row_booking_id");
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is the recursive function (`getPhotoCountForSyncItemSuccessRecursive`) which should only be called again once the `getPhotoCountForSyncItem` function is complete is firing before then. Any suggestion as to what is wrong? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Shit dude, nearly 3 year old question and no one can help you...? How are you going to finish this project???